# What gives amorphous solids their solidity?

Tags: solid-state-physics, amorphous-solids

I understand that amorphous solids (like glass and plastic) don't have a symmetric lattice structure to their molecules or atoms, as do typical solids. It is often said that their molecules are arranged in disorderly structures similar to those of liquids.

In that case, **what is the difference between amorphous solids and liquids that allows amorphous solids to have solid-like properties?**

Is it:

- The strength of inter-molecular bonds?
- The number of inter-molecular bonds?
- The shapes of molecules and geometry of their (disordered) arrangement?

Comment: Basically all three points can contribute. All that is hindering sliding and roll sliding results in viscosity. Spherical fullerene and graphite are two solid lubricants.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the average number of intermolecular bonds between any given molecule and it nearest neighbors in an amorphous solid is similar to that of the molecules in an ordered/crystalline solid, there is no reason to expect that their bulk strengths would be significantly different.

Comment: And, without dislocation action, they will remain elastic longer (usually)...